# Why can't I remove this form?

Tags: jquery, forms, dom

I'm using the [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function from within jQuery to try and remove a form from a DIV on a page that I've created but it doesn't see to work. Is there anything wrong with my code?

I've used an alert to see if the actual line is being fired and it definitely is. Basically I have a delete button on a page, which I'm hoping will remove the last form added but it doesn't do this. I saw the [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/) function but don't know if I can use it in this context?

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Delete Row" class="removePlacement button blue" />

<div id="placement">
<form id="placement-form" class="placement-form">
    <!-- items -->
</form>
 <form id="placement-form1" class="placement-form">
    <!-- items -->
</form>
 <form id="placement-form2" class="placement-form">
    <!-- items -->
</form>
 <form id="placement-form3" class="placement-form">
    <!-- items -->
</form>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$('.removePlacement').click(function() {
    $('#placement').remove('form').last();
    // alert('0');
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function() {
    $('.removePlacement').click(function() {
        $('#placement').find("form:last").remove();
        // alert('0');
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#placement').remove('form').last();
```

What you are telling jQuery to do here is:

1. Find the `placement` container.
2. Remove any element of type `form` since you specified only a type (form, not a specific selector for a class or particular element).
3. Return last on the results of the remove operation--which won't have anything to return.

karim's explanation should fix it. However, hopefully this clears up *why* your code was behaving like that.

Comment: Yeah this does. Thanks dude. Just getting to grips with JQuery and thinking, it's a great language!

Comment: @Kiz jQuery is *not* a language. It's a DOM library.

Comment: Fair play. That's true. JavaScript is the language. D'oh!